# Testing two result.next()

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I would need help to know why one of my prepared statement are not executed. here is the code :

The prepared statement :

```
updaterBalance = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE account_id = ?")
```

The table :

```
statmnt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE accounts ( account_id INTEGER, balance DOUBLE PRECISION)");

statmnt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT balance_must_be_positive CHECK (balance >= 0)");
```

The failing method :

```
 public boolean transfer(int from, int to, double amount) throws DataStoreException {

  try {
    lookForAccount.setInt(1, to);
    ResultSet result = lookForAccount.executeQuery();

            if(result.next()) {

                result.close();

                lookForAccount.setInt(1, from);
                ResultSet result2 = lookForAccount.executeQuery();


                if(result2.next()) {
                    updaterBalance.setDouble(1, result2.getDouble("balance") - amount);
                    updaterBalance.setInt(2, from);
                    updaterBalance.executeUpdate();
                    result2.close();

                    updaterBalance.setDouble(1, result2.getDouble("balance") + amount);
                    updaterBalance.setInt(2, to);
                    updaterBalance.executeUpdate();

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                   return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

          } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
                return false;
    }
```

}

The call :

```
 boolean a = manager.transfer(1, 2, 10);
```

The prepared statement works perfectly fine is a addMoney method that add money on a single specified account_id. At the moment of the call, there is 1000 in balance for the first account_id and 0 for the second.
I never went in the if block. I simply can't fullfil the conditions.

Any idea ?

Comment: You are using random indentations which makes your code very difficult to read and understand. Please help us help you by striving to post well formatted and easy to understand code.

Comment: I will try to edit for you this time, but in the future your cooperation in doing this yourself would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited. Is it better now ?

Comment: As mentioned, I already edited your question to fix the formatting, and in fact your current re-edit goes against what many consider to be Java code standard formatting. But I'm mainly referring to future questions on this site. Remember that you're asking volunteers to help you in their free time, and so you should put in this effort without our having to ask in the future.

Comment: ok, i understand. I didn't see you edited, we did it more or less at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says:

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement`
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an
>   open one exists.

This basically means that because you used the same `lookForAccount` statement for both `result` and `result2`, `result` is being closed, so `result.next()` will not return `true`.

Comment: Oh, that's how it works ? I'll correct that, thank you

Comment: @RealSkeptic I edited the original post to show my corrections on the method. Now i got an error "java.sql.SQLException: Exhaust Resultset". What does it means ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : i found. I just remove all resulset.close().

Comment: @Csi I think just moving the `result2.close()` a little further down would have worked. The problem was that you were still using `result2.getDouble()` after that `close()`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i changed the code and use only one result in the whole method now. I'll add a result.close() after, thx, i learn a lot :)